# Alarm Manager does not broadcast on sleep mode

Tags: android, alarm, android-wake-lock

I have android device which is always connected to the power and device is rooted as well.
i put my device in sleep mode using command "input keyevent 26" and schedule a exact alarm of pending intent of getBroadcast() which reboots the device.

But alarm is not fired on sleep mode.

Please suggest what to do for this to fire alarm in sleep mode.

Here are some piece of code

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PlayerActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis() + (delays * 1000));
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, dateTime.getHourOfDay());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dateTime.getMinuteOfHour());
mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        L.v("AlarmReceiver called.");
        final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        final PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "ImsWakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        wakeLock.release();
        try {
            final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot"});
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            L.w("Could not reboot", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Are you certain the alarm didn't fire, or is it possible it fired, but the reboot code didn't work?

Comment: Yes i am confirmed alarm not fired.

Comment: I print a some logs in file in onReceive() but no log there.

Comment: Does the alarm fire OK if the machine is not asleep at the time?  Does your manifest include the permission android.permission.WAKE_LOCK ?

Comment: Yes i have given all permissions required.

Comment: What is your Android version, device and manufacturer and system? (e.g. miui/emui/samsung (from 2015) have some battery savers which disable all events in alarmmanager exclude exactly enabled apps)

Comment: Its is device manufactured by RKM and it is rooted as well,there is no battery inside its always connected to power whenever it run.
actually its a media player which plays all types of media contents .My application is put in its firmware.